Automorphisms of the circle as an affine algebraic set (equivalently, automorphisms of the $K$-algebra $K[x, y]/\langle x^2 + y^2 - 1 \rangle$)
Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field. Let $R = K[x, y]/\langle x^2 + y^2 - 1 \rangle$. Let $V = \mathcal{V}(x^2 + y^2 - 1) \subseteq \mathbb{A}_K^2$ be the circle considered as an affine algebraic set. What is $\operatorname{Aut}_K(R)$? Equivalently, what is $\operatorname{Aut}_{\operatorname{Aff}}(V)$?
I have been able to identify some elements of the automorphism group, but I'm unsure whether they generate the full automorphism group:

We have a reflection
$$
s: V \to V, (x, y) \mapsto (x, -y)
$$
Equivalently, this is the $K$-algebra map
$$
R \to R, x \mapsto x, y \mapsto -y
$$
Note that if $\operatorname{char} K = 2$, this map is the identity.

For any $a, b \in K$ such that $a^2 + b^2 = 1$, we have a rotation map
$$
V \to V, (x, y) \mapsto (ax+by, -bx+ay)
$$
Indeed,
$$
(ax+by)^2 + (-bx+ay)^2 = a^2x^2+b^2y^2+2axby+b^2x^2+a^2y^2-2bxay = (a^2 + b^2)(x^2 + y^2) = 1
$$
Equivalently, this is the $K$-algebra map
$$
r_{a,b}: R \to R, x \mapsto ax+by, y \mapsto -bx+ay
$$


Now, does $\langle \{s\} \cup \{r_{a, b} \mid a^2 + b^2 = 1\} \rangle = \operatorname{Aut}_{\operatorname{Aff}}(V)$? Or can there be more automorphisms? Is it at least true in the case of $K = \mathbb{C}$?

Hint: if the characteristic is not 2, the algebra is isomorphic to $K[U,V]/\langle UV-1 \rangle = K[U,U^{-1}]$. This makes it much easier to handle. Actually I would not be surprised if this example already appeared on the site.

@MartinBrandenburg I presume the isomorphism is given by $K[U, V]/\langle UV - 1 \rangle \to K[x, y]/\langle x^2 + y^2 - 1\rangle, U \mapsto x + iy, V \mapsto x - iy$ where $x^2 + 1 = (x + i)(x - i)$, which is an isomorphism due to $\operatorname{char} K \neq 2$?

And in characteristic $2$ the algebra is isomorphic to $K[U][V]/\langle V^2\rangle$. Also quite easy to handle in this form.

@MartinBrandenburg Thanks for the hints. I think I figured it out: If $\operatorname{char} K \neq 2$, the subgroup generated by the elements I gave indeed gives the full automorphism group, but if $\operatorname{char} K = 2$, the automorphism group is larger.

We consider the cases $\operatorname{char} K \neq 2$ and $\operatorname{char} K = 2$ separately.

First of all, let's consider the case $\operatorname{char} K \neq 2$.
In this case, we know that since $K$ is algebraically closed, we have $x^2 + 1 = (x - i)(x - j)$ for some $i, j \in K$. Then $i + j = 0$ and $ij = 1$, hence $j = -i$, so we can write $x^2 + 1 = (x - i)(x + i)$.
Consider the ring homomorphism
$$
\alpha: K[z, w] \to K[x, y]/\langle x^2 + y^2 - 1 \rangle, \\ z \mapsto x + iy, w \mapsto x - iy
$$
We also have $\alpha(zw - 1) = \alpha(z)\alpha(w) - 1 = (x + iy)(x - iy) - 1 = x^2 + y^2 - 1 = 0$. Hence $\langle zw - 1 \rangle \subseteq \operatorname{ker}(\alpha)$, so we get a map
$$
\tilde{\alpha}: K[z, w]/\langle zw - 1 \rangle \to K[x, y]/\langle x^2 + y^2 - 1 \rangle
$$
Due to $\operatorname{char} K \neq 2$, we can also define
$$
\beta: K[x, y] \to K[z, w]/\langle zw - 1 \rangle, \\ x \mapsto \frac{1}{2}(z + w), y \mapsto \frac{1}{2i}(z - w)
$$
Again we have $\beta(x^2 + y^2 - 1) = \beta(x)^2 + \beta(y)^2 - 1 = \frac{1}{4}(z^2 + 2zw + w^2) - \frac{1}{4}(z^2 - 2zw + w^2) - 1 = zw - 1 = 0$. Hence we get a map
$$
\tilde{\beta}: K[x, y]/\langle x^2 + y^2 - 1 \rangle \to K[z, w]/\langle zw - 1 \rangle
$$
It can now be checked that $\tilde{\alpha} \circ \tilde{\beta} = \operatorname{id}$ and $\tilde{\beta} \circ \tilde{\alpha} = \operatorname{id}$, hence they are both isomorphisms.
We now have
$$
\tilde{\beta} \circ s \circ \tilde{\alpha}: K[z, w]/\langle zw - 1 \rangle \to K[z, w]/\langle zw - 1 \rangle, \\ z \mapsto w, w \mapsto z
$$
and
$$
\tilde{\beta} \circ r_{a, b} \circ \tilde{\alpha}: K[z, w]/\langle zw - 1 \rangle \to K[z, w]/\langle zw - 1 \rangle, \\ z \mapsto (a - ib)z, w \mapsto (a + ib)w
$$
Now consider an arbitary automorphism
$$
\gamma: K[z, w]/\langle zw - 1 \rangle \to K[z, w]/\langle zw - 1 \rangle
$$
Following https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2232967/491450, we can argue as follows: $\gamma(z)$ must be sent to an invertible element, but the invertible elements of $K[z, w]/\langle zw - 1 \rangle$ are just the $c z^n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $c \in K^{\times}$. For surjectivity it is clearly required that $n = \pm 1$. We see that the automorphisms of $K[z, w]/\langle zw - 1 \rangle$ are just the maps given by $z \mapsto c z^n$.
Now, indeed, the map $z \mapsto z^{-1}$ is just $\tilde{\beta} \circ s \circ \tilde{\alpha}$. Also, given some $c \in K^{\times}$, let $a = \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{c} + c\right)$ and $b = \frac{1}{2i} \left(\frac{1}{c} - c\right)$. Then we have $a^2 + b^2 = \frac{1}{4} \left(\frac{1}{c^2} + 2 + c^2 - \frac{1}{c^2} + 2 - c^2\right) = 1$ and $a - ib = c$. Thus we see that every automorphism of $K[z, w]/\langle zw - 1 \rangle$ can be written as a product of $\tilde{\beta} \circ s \circ \tilde{\alpha}$ and some $\tilde{\beta} \circ r_{a, b} \circ \tilde{\alpha}$. Hence every automorphism of $K[x, y]/\langle x^2 + y^2 - 1 \rangle$ can be written as a product of $s$ and some $r_{a, b}$.
So in this case, the answer is positive.

Second of all, let's consider the case $\operatorname{char} K = 2$.
Consider the map
$$
\alpha: K[z, w] \to K[x, y]/\langle x^2 + y^2 + 1 \rangle, \\ z \mapsto x, w \mapsto x + y + 1
$$
We have $\alpha(w^2) = \alpha(w)^2 = (x + y + 1)^2 = x^2 + y^2 + 1$. Hence $\alpha$ factors through
$$
\tilde{\alpha}: K[z, w]/\langle w^2 \rangle \to K[x, y]/\langle x^2 + y^2 + 1 \rangle
$$
Now consider
$$
\beta: K[x, y] \to K[z, w]/\langle w^2 \rangle, \\ x \mapsto z, y \mapsto w + z + 1
$$
Then we have $\beta(x^2 + y^2 + 1) = \beta(x)^2 + \beta(y)^2 + 1 = z^2 + (w + z + 1)^2 + 1 = z^2 + w^2 + z^2 + 1 + 1 = w^2$. Hence $\beta$ factors through
$$
\tilde{\beta}: K[x, y]/\langle x^2 + y^2 + 1 \rangle \to K[z, w]/\langle w^2 \rangle
$$
It can now be checked that $\tilde{\alpha} \circ \tilde{\beta} = \operatorname{id}$ and $\tilde{\beta} \circ \tilde{\alpha} = \operatorname{id}$, hence they are both isomorphisms.
Since we had $s = \operatorname{id}$, we also have $\tilde{\beta} \circ s \circ \tilde{\alpha} = \operatorname{id}$. But we have
$$
\tilde{\beta} \circ r_{a, b} \circ \tilde{\alpha}: K[z, w]/\langle w^2 \rangle \to K[z, w]/\langle w^2 \rangle, \\ z \mapsto (a + b)z + bw + b, w \mapsto (a + b)w + (a + b) + 1
$$
But now consider the automorphism
$$
\gamma: K[z, w]/\langle w^2 \rangle \to K[z, w]/\langle w^2 \rangle, \\ z \mapsto z + zw, w \mapsto w
$$
It is its own inverse. We clearly cannot find $a, b \in K$ with $\gamma = \tilde{\beta} \circ r_{a, b} \circ \tilde{\alpha}$.
Transferring this to the original ring, we find
$$
\tilde{\alpha} \circ \gamma \circ \tilde{\beta}: K[x, y]/\langle x^2 + y^2 + 1 \rangle \to K[x, y]/\langle x^2 + y^2 + 1 \rangle, \\ x \mapsto x^2 + xy, y \mapsto x^2 + xy + x + y
$$
Again, this is self-inverse. This is an automorphism of $K[x, y]/\langle x^2 + y^2 + 1 \rangle$ which is clearly not of the form $r_{a, b}$ for any $a, b \in K$.
Hence in this case the answer is negative.

Did you try to find a full classification for char 2? It's also doable.

@MartinBrandenburg I didn't try that yet. I think I figured out that any automorphism has to map $z$ to an expression of the form $(a + wb) + z(c + wd)$ where $a, b, d \in K$ and $c \in K^{\times}$. Also, $w$ has to be sent to another nilpotent element, and these are just the multiples of $w$. I didn't find out anything more. Can you give a hint?

I have posted an answer about this.

As already mentioned, in characteristic $2$ we are left with the commutative $K$-algebra $K[T][\varepsilon]/\langle \varepsilon^2 \rangle$. Let us consider more generally the $K$-algebra $R[\varepsilon]/\varepsilon^2$ of dual numbers over $R$, where $R$ is a reduced commutative $K$-algebra, and determine its automorphisms (over $K$, not over $R$).
The nilradical of $R[\varepsilon]/\varepsilon^2$ is $\langle \varepsilon \rangle = R \cdot \varepsilon$. Any algebra automorphism $\alpha : R[\varepsilon]/\varepsilon^2 \to R[\varepsilon]/\varepsilon^2$ induces a module-automorphism of the nilradical, but also an algebra automorphism $\overline{\alpha}$ of its reduced quotient $R[\varepsilon]/\varepsilon^2 / \varepsilon = R$. Any automorphism of $R$ lifts to an automorphism of $R[\varepsilon]/\varepsilon^2$, and by composing the inverse of that with $\alpha$, we may as well assume for the moment that $\overline{\alpha}=\mathrm{id}$. This means that we can write
$$\alpha|_R(r) = r + d(r) \varepsilon$$
for some map $d : R \to R$. The fact that $\alpha|_R : R \to R[\varepsilon]/\varepsilon^2$ is a homomorphism of $K$-algebras precisely means that $d$ is a $K$-derivation. The only remaining data of $\alpha$ is the image $\alpha(\varepsilon) = s \cdot \varepsilon$ with $s \in R$. This means $\alpha$ is given by
$$\alpha(r + r'\varepsilon) = (r + d(r)\varepsilon) + (r' + d(r')\varepsilon) s \varepsilon = r + (d(r) + r's) \varepsilon.$$
With this, a direct calculation shows that $\alpha$ is surjective if and only $s \in R^{\times}$, and that in this case $\alpha$ is also injective. I omit the proof since it is straight forward. This proves:
There is a bijection
$$\mathrm{Aut}_K(R) \times \mathrm{Der}_K(R) \times R^{\times} \xrightarrow{~ \cong ~} \mathrm{Aut}_K(R[\varepsilon]/\varepsilon^2),$$
mapping a triple $(\pi,d,s)$ to the automorphism defined by
$$r + r' \varepsilon \mapsto \pi(r) + (d(\pi(r)) + \pi(r')s) \varepsilon.$$
We can simplify this a bit for $R = K[T]$, since then $\mathrm{Aut}_K(K[T]) \cong K \rtimes K^{\times}$ (affine maps), $\mathrm{Der}_K(K[T]) \cong K[T]$ and $K[T]^{\times} \cong K^{\times}$.

Your bijection isn't necessarily a group isomorphism though, right?

Well you need to define the correct group structure. It will be a semidirect product. I didn't write it down yet. You can figure it out. :) Then it will be an isomorphism of groups.
